# Qualified name of a local class

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

`typename` keyword in a declaration requires a qualified type name after it (a type name with a nested name spacifier in front of it). But what is a qualified name of a local class or struct? Here is the example:

```
struct A{};
namespace bb { struct B{}; }
int main()
{
    struct C{};

    typename A a; // not OK, because A is not a qualified typename
    typename ::A a; // OK, because it contains a nested name specifier
    typename B b; // not OK, because B is not a qualified typename
    typename bb::B b; // OK, because it contains a nested name specifier
    typename C c; // not OK in gcc and clang but compiles in Visual Studio
}
```

This is the error I get from clang: `expected a qualified name after 'typename'`

This is the error reported by gcc: `<source>:21:14: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'C'`

Is it possible to use a local class name after `typename`? If so then what is the qualified name of it? The class is reported as `main()::C` in clang error messages, but that obviously is not its qualified name. I couldn't find a place in the C++ standard that forbids using local classes in this context. Am I missing something? Visual Studio is not complaining about `typename C c;` so is it a bug in gcc and clang?

PS. I know I can declare variables without typename in front of them if I don't use templates, but I am just curious if this is a bug in the language, a bug in gcc/clang or Visual Studio, or I am missing something.

Comment: "Is it possible to use a local class name after typename". Why?

Comment: @Klaus as I wrote in the question I am asking this out of curiosity

Comment: Looking for the details is sometimes as knocking on the backdoor of hell in C++ :-)

Comment: VS is known to be not very conformant.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like gcc and clang are stricter and correct, while VS is more permissive (not sure if it qualifies as a bug).

As you've correctly written already, `typename` requires a qualified name. That is "a name that appears on the right hand side of the scope resolution operator `::`". There is no way of using `::` with local class, which means that there is no `::`-qualified name for one (so, as in the definition quoted above). Whether such requirement has a good logic or not, posterity will probably decide, but for what is worth, the following does work:

```
int main()
{
    struct C { public: struct D{}; };

    typename C::D d; // ok

    return 0;
}
```

Also probably worth mentioning, using `typename` outside a template was permitted starting with `c++11`, in case older compilers are used.

Answer (score -1):

Nice experiment. I never thought about to instantiate structs using `typename`. I created addtional code and was wondering that it worked:

```
struct C{
    int c = 1;
};
void foo(){
    struct C{
        int c = 0;
    };

    typename ::C c;
    C c_;
    std::cout << "c.c: " << c.c << std::endl; //c.c: 1
    std::cout << "c_.c: " << c_.c << std::endl; //c_.c: 0

    return;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

I guess the reason why `typename C c;` does not work, is that there exists no linkage for structs defined within functions. The keyword `typename` indicates that a `type` is following. But the compiler/linker is not able to find it.

Please let me know if my assumption is correct or wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: But why it works in Visual Studio then? I also couldn't find anything in the spec that supports your assumption. Also the error is not being reported by the linker, but it is reported by the parsers/compiler.

Comment: I used the gcc-9.3.0 compiler to analyse the effect of the exchangeability of `typename` and `class`.
Using`class C c;` instead of `typename ::C c;` in function `foo()` works!. The nested C struct within the function was correctly choosen by the compiler. Although the keyword `typename` does not compile.

So this might not be forbidden by the C++ standard. But it is also unusual/not necessary to use the prefix `typename` while instantiating variables when obviously a type is following. Therefore each compiler might handle it different.

Comment: Prepending type with `class` means referring to the type using its elaborated type specifier (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier) instead of its tag name (https://www.embedded.com/tag-vs-type-names/). That has nothing to do with `typename` in this context.